# ECU problem Daihatsu Sirron M3 1.0

Tags: random-misfire, daihatsu

Daihatsu Sirion M3 1.0 Petrol

Engine misfire and 3 random cylinder not working. Coil is working, but not checked the injectors. I bought an identical ECU on eBay, but not working.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the fuel pressure at the rail? If so, what is the pressure reading? I take it the random misfires are codes present in the ECU? Any other codes? And, I'd go back to your original ECU as the ECU is about the last thing I'd suspect in any vehicle. Lots to troubleshoot before you go to a different ECU.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you very much for advised, resolved the problem with old ECU, thanks again